# ProFTPD won't start or restart

Tags: proftpd

I have so far: installed ProFTPD, turned ipv6 off in the conf, changed server name from Debian to jon-virtual-machine, and jailed users to their home folder. But it says I can't determine IP address or process the conf file.

Comment: Sorry for lack of info i went with VSFTPD instead all is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer this question because of lack of information provided (`proftpd.conf`, `/etc/hosts`, output of `ifconfig` and `hostname`).
I guess it's a problem related to your changed hostname. If so, try to modify your `/etc/hosts` from:

```
x.y.z.t Debian
```

where `x.y.z.t` is your actual IP address, to:

```
x.y.z.t jon-virtual-machine
```

I've supposed your `hostname` output is `jon-virtual-machine`.

Let me know if it's the case.